# Glassmapper | Cannot save a class that does not contain a property that represents the item ID

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

Environment: Sitecore 9.0.2 + Glass Mapper

I have a class like this:

```
public class Sample
{
    public Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image Logo { get; set; }

    public string Destination_Name { get; set; }
    public bool Is_Atttraction { get; set; }

    public string ID { get; set; }

    public Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link Explore_More_Link { get; set; }

    public ProductCardViewModel productCardViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

The component loads properly on the website. Inside the experience editor, it breaks and I have a message like below:

```
Failed item resolve - You cannot save a class that does not contain a property that represents the item ID. Ensure that at least one property has been marked to contain the Sitecore ID. Type: **NameOfMyClass**
```

Any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to change your `ID` property to type `Guid`. Also, you can add the attribute `SitecoreId` to the property.

```
[SitecoreId]
public Guid ID { get; set; }
```

This should allow Glass to map to your class properly.  You can see a really basic example of this on the Glass Mapper website: http://glass.lu/Mapper