# String not geting rendered in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

Environment: Sitecore 9.0.2 + Glass mapper

I have a model class like this:

```
public class SingleStack
    {
        public Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image Logo { get; set; }

        public string Attraction_Name { get; set; }
        public string Destination_Name { get; set; }
        public bool Is_Atttraction { get; set; }

        [SitecoreId]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

       public Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link Explore_More_Link { get; set; }


    }
```

From a list of object of class SingleStack, I am displaying the fields.
On my website, everything is fine.

The situation changes in the Experience Editor.

The fields `Attraction_Name` and `Destination_Name` are not getting rendered. `Logo` and `Explore_More_Link` are getting rendered and editable.

Few points to note:
1. All the fields are coming from the same item in Sitecore.

2. The `ID` field contains the GUID of the item being rendered.

Code to render in cshtml:

```
     @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stack.Destination_Name))
{
@Html.Glass().Editable(stack, x => x.Destination_Name)
    }
```

There are no errors in console and log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last question and this question I am adding some details-

In Glass mapper, two types of Models are being in use called - **Template Models** and **Rendering Models** - See more here - http://glass.lu/Blog/TemplateVsRendering

It seems you are using Rendering Models, these are models that are designed to contain just the properties required by a rendering. Rendering Models have some limitations, one of them is that it is difficult to link properties to the fields in Sitecore because the field name or display name in Sitecore name may differ and may contains space in it.

I will suggest you, to create a list of field name constants and then use attribute or fluent configuration to link these names to the properties on your view models -

```
[SitecoreField("Your Field Name")]
public string Destination_Name { get; set; }
```

or

```
public class SingleStack
    {
        [SitecoreField(Templates._SingleStack.Fields.Logo)]
    public Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image Logo { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(Templates._SingleStack.Fields.AttractionName)]
    public string Attraction_Name { get; set; }

     [SitecoreField(Templates._SingleStack.Fields.DestinationName)]
    public string Destination_Name { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(Templates._SingleStack.Fields.IsAtttraction)]
    public bool Is_Atttraction { get; set; }

    [SitecoreId]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

   [SitecoreField(Templates._SingleStack.Fields.Explore_More_Link)]
   public Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link ExploreMoreLink { get; set; }    

    }
```

Where `SitecoreField(Templates._SingleStack.Fields` will have all your field names, make sure your field name is correct.

Comment: Thanks for taking out the time to explain this. If someone is looking for the previous question mentioned by Mahendra, here is the link https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22521/glassmapper-cannot-save-a-class-that-does-not-contain-a-property-that-represen/22523#22523